# What could cause "invalid object name" when I'd expect "Could not find server 'dbtest' in sys.servers"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 Web Edition, entirely within SQL Management Studio. I need to do a cross-server query but my query always returns "Invalid object name", regardless of whether the server is linked. Changing the server name returns "Could not find server", exactly as I would expect.

I've added and removed the linked database several times using sp_addlinkedserver and sp_dropserver, checked the sys.Servers table and I've tried various permutations of the queries. My guess is that it's another feature with the same 4-part name syntax as linked servers.

For example, the following return "Invalid object name"

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbtest.Web.dbo.tblProduct -- this is correct
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbtest.Web.dbo.tblProductFake
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbtest.WebFake.dbo.tblProduct
```

If I deliberately change the server name to something incorrect, the following return "Could not find server", as I would expect

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbtestFake.Web.dbo.tblProduct
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbtest1.Web.dbo.tblProduct
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbtst.Fake.dbo.tblProduct
```

Queries against another linked server from the same database either return results, or return "The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "dbx" does not contain the table" depending on whether the query is correct, again, all as I would expect.

What's even weirder is that I can get Management Studio to build the query for me following "Server Objects" > "Linked Servers" and so on, then clicking "Script Table as SELECT to new query window", but that query will still show "Invalid object name".

Comment: `cross-database query` is a term used for databases on the same server. You would reference objects in it using `otherdb.dbo.tablename`. Linked servers are a very different thing and involve a 4-part name `linkedserver.dbname.dbo.tablename`

Comment: Thanks, corrected. Just for clarity it is a 4-part name.

Comment: What's the part of the query causing the error (the part where you address the object)?

Comment: I've given examples in the question.

Comment: Does the query work if you run it on the target server under the same security context as the linked server connection? (i.e. `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Web.dbo.tblProduct` executed on the "dbtest" server, using whatever credentials are used by the linked server)

Comment: Yes, the credentials used for both are sa and they share a password (I obviously wouldn't do that in a production environment, these are test servers). I also compared the security settings for the other linked server that works.

Comment: How does the query appear in a trace running against the target server?